# Stopping a Azure VM in auto scale set and letting it start again

Tags: azure-vm-scale-set

I have 3 VMs in my Azure autoscale set. My question is if I stop one of the VMs using the Azure Portal manually (i.e. deallocate it) will the AutoScale Set be able to start it again?

I have been through [this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/gbanin/2015/04/22/difference-between-the-states-of-azure-virtual-machines-stopped-and-stopped-deallocated/) but it still doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. Autoscale will not start a deallocated VM in a scale set :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of starting the deallocated VM, if usage was high enough to trigger scale-out, Autoscale would create a new VM.

The deallocated VM would remain deallocated until you started it, issued a start to the scale set, or until it was deleted by autoscale scaling in.

Comment: So summarizing your statements "Autoscale won't start the VM if it was deallocated manually from the portal right?"

Comment: Right. Autoscale creates and deletes VMs, it doesn't start existing ones.